# InfraValidator component not "blessing" my model

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, tfx

The InfraValidator TFX component is not blessing my model, and I'm having trouble finding out why it isn't getting "blessed". I'm not sure what part of my model would be causing it to not be "mechanically sound" enough to not get validated.

This component is using a local docker server.

Github Link: https://github.com/BikiniBottomsVeryOwn/tfx_pipeline

I configured the InfraValidator exactly as it's configured in the API docs.

I ran the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker and it worked with Docker.

Comment: I am new for InfraValidator but does it required signatures ?

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/infra_validator

Comment: Data management service specs ?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, I've gotten InfraValidator to work, and other times it hasn't worked.  The times that it didn't work, it was because the particular tensor ops were not available on the serving container.  I would recommend looking at https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker and recreating the example they have, and then trying to recreate the same example with your own model/data.  Best of luck!